# Laws, advice and limitations on "lying for the sake of shalom"

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, sheker-false, shalom-peace

Emet (truth) in general, and interpersonal honesty in specific are some of the most valued and imperative concepts in all of Torah. Throughout all Torah writings, it seems there is nothing more valuable or necessary than truth. I can bring 100 sources, but for brevity, I'll just bring this (Avot 1:18):

> רַבָּן שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן גַּמְלִיאֵל אוֹמֵר,**עַל שְׁלשָׁה דְבָרִים
> הָעוֹלָם עוֹמֵד**, עַל הַדִּין וְעַל הָאֱמֶת וְעַל הַשָּׁלוֹם,
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (זכריה ח) אֱמֶת וּמִשְׁפַּט שָׁלוֹם שִׁפְטוּ
> בְּשַׁעֲרֵיכֶם:
>
> Rabban Shimon ben Gamaliel used to say: **on three things does the world
> stand**: On justice, **on truth and on peace**, as it is said: “execute the
> judgment of truth and peace in your gates” (Zechariah 8:16).

Note that truth, and peace, are both pillars that hold up the whole world. When truth and peace come into conflict, who wins?

There is a source that said that in order to preserve peace, we should sacrifice truth (Yevamot 65b).

> וְאָמַר רַבִּי אִילְעָא מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר בְּרַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן:
> **מוּתָּר לוֹ לָאָדָם לְשַׁנּוֹת בִּדְבַר הַשָּׁלוֹם**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר:
> ״אָבִיךְ צִוָּה וְגוֹ׳ כֹּה תֹאמְרוּ לְיוֹסֵף אָנָּא שָׂא נָא וְגוֹ׳״.
>
> And Rabbi Ile’a further said in the name of Rabbi Elazar, son of Rabbi
> Shimon: **It is permitted for a person to depart from the truth in a
> matter that will bring peace**, as it is stated: “Your father commanded
> before he died, saying: So you shall say to Joseph: Please pardon your
> brothers’ crime, etc.” (Genesis 50:16–17)
>
> רַבִּי נָתָן אוֹמֵר: **מִצְוָה**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וַיֹּאמֶר שְׁמוּאֵל אֵיךְ
> אֵלֵךְ וְשָׁמַע שָׁאוּל וַהֲרָגָנִי וְגוֹ׳״.
>
> Rabbi Natan says: **It is a mitzva [to depart from the truth in order to
> preserve peace]**, as it is stated: “And Samuel said: How can I go, and
> Saul will hear and kill me” (I Samuel 16:2)
>
> דְּבֵי רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל תָּנָא: **גָּדוֹל הַשָּׁלוֹם, שֶׁאַף
> הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא שִׁינָּה בּוֹ**, דְּמֵעִיקָּרָא כְּתִיב:
> ״וַאֲדוֹנִי זָקֵן״, וּלְבַסּוֹף, כְּתִיב: ״וַאֲנִי זָקַנְתִּי״.
>
> It was taught in the school of Rabbi Yishmael: **Great is peace, as even
> the Holy One, Blessed be He, departed from the truth for it**. As,
> initially it is written that Sarah said of Abraham: “And my lord is
> old” (Genesis 18:12), and in the end it is written that God told
> Abraham that Sarah said: “And I am old” (Genesis 18:13)

[This article](https://etzion.org.il/en/talmud/studies-gemara/midrash-and-aggada/lying-sake-peace) outlines several problems with all of the above points in the gemara, better than I could. It's important to what I am about to bring although it doesn't focus on it.

My issue is that the nature of deceit and lying is so all-encompassingly dangerous, it beggars belief that we are permitted to do it. It would appear to me that if indeed we can prove it is permitted (or even a mitzva), **it should come with a huge amount of warning, commentary and rules to make it work**. Let me just list some of the dangers to make the point:

### Trust is vital

We can never know what a person is really thinking or feeling, so getting close to others, whether it be in an intimate relationship or any functional relationship, requires the positive establishment of trust in order to function. Even if we have a moral reason to lie, certainly we should be very very careful and decide if it is absolutely necessary, as if we are caught lying, we do untold damage to our reputation and our relationships! We are not God, and we cannot know if we will or will not be caught. That's rarely something we can predict or control.

Certainly, if the person catches us but believes we were doing it for their sake and benefit, it helps a little, but not much. From now on, every time one speaks to them, they will be suspecting "is he lying for my benefit?". Not only that, but they might feel disrespected, or infantilised. "I am an adult and can look after myself, please stop trying to protect me". This can easily breed resentment and be a stumbling block for וְלֹֽא־תִטֹּר֙.

### It breeds arrogance

Empowering a person to deceive people for their benefit sends a bad message. It says "you are better than the people around you, in that you can decide matters relevant to their benefit, without consulting them, and act on those decisions". It is not even behind their back, but direct, they will go and say cunning, pre-meditated words to them that will directly affect them in one of the most penimiusdik ways imaginable - modifying their very knowledge.

Giving people the power to make important decisions on behalf of other people without consulting them creates a huge stumbling block for arrogance. It makes a person believe they are smarter than those around him, and makes them seem to him to be like infants in his eyes, that need him to look after them. Worse still, we learn this lesson, apparently, from God! "Be like God, lie to people when *you* decide it would be for their benefit". Yikes.

### It is dangerous - how are we supposed to know what's best?

Permission to lie for the sake of shalom is giving us a lot more credit than we deserve. As humans, we are very limited. Unlike Hashem, who is omniscient, we are lacking 99.9% of the knowledge and information necessary to be able to know with confidence that the lie is better than the truth in any situation. Even if we knew that a certain lie would produce shalom in the moment, we can't know if it will in the long run.

Telling someone their clothing looks good when we know it doesn't, may prevent an argument in that conversation, but we have no idea what an all-encompassing effect this person believing their clothes, erroneously, look good will have on their life as a whole. People might think of them as weird and treat them badly, they might fail job interviews or lose their job, they may get mocked and attacked. Often, a little bit of stirring of shalom is a good thing.

Note, I am not now saying we should do something equally difficult - take it into our own hands to stir shalom when we think it's of benefit. That suffers from all the same issues here. I am simply arguing that truth is vital. If truth and shalom come into conflict, I am advocating for truth over shalom. It's hard to imagine how telling the truth can ever lead to something that *shouldn't be*. The most basic, default opinion is that telling the truth will always lead to the *right* outcome. So therefore if telling the truth will stir shalom, then I don't see why that's such a huge problem? In fact, it takes bravery to be able to do this and this leads to my next point.

### Lying is easy, telling the truth can be difficult

In a situation where telling the truth will be difficult, the yeitzer is to lie. Given that lying in general is a very big aveira, a big temptation, and can be easier than telling the truth, it's dangerous to give people any level of permission to do it. Torah highly praises going against our nature in order to pursue virtue (e.g. Avraham's 10th test). In light of everything I am saying here, surely the number of cases where taking the easy route and lying for the sake of shalom must be a very tiny percentage of real-life situations? This leads to the next point.

### It is ill defined

Surely, if we are going to allow "lying for the sake of shalom", we need to define it very rigorously, and there should be as many halachot about it as there are about Lashon Hara. Almost any time we are tempted to lie, an argument can be made that it will be of benefit to shalom. Lying to cover up a sin or crime we did, for example, would be of benefit to shalom because getting caught will cause hurt feelings, arguments, chillul Hashem etc. Just having a well known permission to "lie for the sake of peace" seems very dangerous.

### It desensitises us to bashfulness and the midda of emet

As is well known (such as from the gemara in Berachot about sinning 3 times), the more we sin, the more sin becomes permissible to us. This is something that is, therefore, forbidden. It destroys our natural born good middot, such as our bashfulness, especially our bashfulness in deceiving others. So, this idea of permitting deception for the sake of shalom is difficult.

Whenever someone does it, they will be inadvertently desensitising themselves to deception. To look someone one loves in the eye, and say over pre-meditated words that deceive them, controlling ones blushing and other "tells", surely has a powerfully negative affect on our middot. It develops skills in the art of deception that we'd rather not have. It makes us better liars and sets a stumbling block for lying more often, through confidence and habituation. Chas veshalom.

---

It is worth noting, that none of the above applies to Hashem, so I find it very difficult that we should learn from Him anything in this regard. It is also noteworthy that we do not have permission to lie for the sake of very important things, like bringing people closer to Hashem (kiruv), the honour of Torah, for raising money for Torah learning or raising money for the poor.

Given all of the above points, it's clear that permission to lie for peace is **not** a simple matter. There are many many issues.

So the question is, what is the *exact* halacha here? Where is it discussed in **full** detail? Ideally one that addresses and mitigates all of the above points.

Comment: מותר לשנות בדבר השלום
Leshannot - not lie but alter -  It's permitted to say a different [version, presentation, of the] truth for the sake of peace  https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance